# Adding a small space in between a header banner and navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a small banner 728x90 pixels between a navigation menu and a list. The current code I am using is:

```
<center><a href="https://imagesite.com/image.gif" /></a></center>
```

I was using the center tag to put the banner in the middle. I just want to add some space on the top of the banner since there is some already on the bottom of it. I need the banner to be responsive.

Comment: and where is navigation menu ? we only see the code of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a margin and/or padding to the top of your centered item

```
<center style="margin-top: 50px"><a href="https://imagesite.com/image.gif"/></center>
```

Comment: i think it's better to explaing that he's using an obsolete tag (center) instead of adding an inline style to it ;)

Answer (score 3):

With much respect, don't use a `<center>` tag.  That is moving the styling into the HTML, which is not preferable / desirable.

Further - inline styles (`<center style="margin-top: 10px;">`) is **horrible** in terms of maintainability.  Avoid these unless absolutely necessary.

Instead, use CSS, combined with a tag that provides a class or ID that is meaningful.

A more useful example of how to do this would be:

HTML:

```
<div id="banner"><a href="https://imagesite.com/image.gif" /></a></div>
```

CSS (in a stylesheet, preferably):

```
#banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0; /* Top Right Bottom Left */
}

/* if the image must be responsive.... */
#banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Update:** 
If you wanted to have the same styles applied to several elements on the page, then instead of an `ID` (which should be unique - only one element on the page should have a given ID) you can use classes:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner"><a href="https://imagesite.com/image.gif" /></a></div>
```

CSS (in a stylesheet, preferably):

```
.banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0; /* Top Right Bottom Left */
}

/* if the image must be responsive.... */
.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: at least a well explained and non-faster answer without simply adding inline margin ;)

Comment: Thanks Cale, can I use this code for a banner on the footer as well, just change the div id?

Comment: @John you can use class instead of ID and then you the same

Comment: @John- I've updated the answer to reflect using a class (so that you can use on multiple elements on the same page)

Answer (score 0):

you use margin or padding to add space around element

```
<center style="margin-top:15px"><a href="https://imagesite.com/image.gif" /></a></center>
```

you can use for each side

```
margin-top
margin-right
margin-bottom
margin-left
```

or juste `margin`

Comment: Thanks, does this make the banner responsive? My website is responsive already.

Comment: the margin or padding will not affect the responsive.

Comment: i think it's better to explaing that he's using an obsolete tag (center) instead of adding an inline style to it ;)